# Matrix equation $X+AX^{-1}A^T=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Given non-singular matrices $A, B \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, is there a way to solve the following matrix equation in matrix unknown $X \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$?

$$X+AX^{-1}A^T=B$$

Comment: What is the source of this problem? Does the question ask "is there a way...?" or just says "solve the equation"?

Comment: The problem arises in time-series analysis. It's not an exercise, therefore I don't know whether the equation can be solved or not.

Comment: Ok, the question sounds better now.

Comment: For $n=1$   (the simplest possible case) we already have a quadratic equation.

Comment: Solved numerically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation can be rewritten as $Y+Y^{-1}P=Q$ where $Y=A^{-1}X,\,P=A^{-1}A^T$ and $Q=A^{-1}B$. Therefore, the problem boils down to solving the quadratic matrix equation (sometimes referred to as a *non-symmetric algebraic Ricatti equation*)
$$
Y^2-YQ+P=0\tag{1}
$$
for $Y$. (Note that when $P$ is nonsingular, any solution $Y$ is automatically nonsingular.) This equation is not always solvable. E.g. when $Q=I$ (i.e., when $A=B$), we have $Y^2-Y+P=0$. Hence $(Y-\frac12I)^2=\frac14I-P$ and solutions exist only if $\frac14I-P$ has a real square root.

I am not familiar with quadratic matrix equations. A quick internet search reveals that for some classes of matrices $P$ and $Q$, necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of solutions are available. See the paper [*Quadratic Matrix Equations*](https://kb.osu.edu/bitstream/handle/1811/22234/V074N5_273.pdf) by Shurbet *et al.* (1974). Numerical methods for solving $(1)$ are studied in the [Ph.D. thesis](https://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/%7Ehigham/links/theses/kim00.pdf) of Hyun-Min Kim (2000).